# The cpu die info by virt-install

Tags: cpu, virtualization, libvirt

I know that the cpu die info can be assigned by XML.

```
<cpu match='exact'>
  <model fallback='allow'>core2duo</model>
  <vendor>Intel</vendor>
  <topology sockets='1' dies='1' cores='2' threads='1'/>
  <cache level='3' mode='emulate'/>
  <feature policy='disable' name='lahf_lm'/>
</cpu>
```

But how does the virt-install assign the cpu die info.

If I use  `--vcpus=16,sockets=2,dies=2,cores=2,threads=2` ,

it says errors:`Unknown --vcpus options: ['dies']`

Answer (score 0):

Skip "dies" in the virt-install command, no such thing under --vcpus:
--vcpus=VCPUS[,maxvcpus=MAX][,sockets=#][,cores=#][,threads=#]

https://linux.die.net/man/1/virt-install